# Express can't upload file, req.files is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I really apologize if I'm leaving something out and am totally stupid, but I've checked and checked over again a number of times, and the file upload functionality is just not working over here. I made a super minimal app to demonstate. Just generated a new express app with the most up-to-date version (3.4.7) and added the least i could to make a file upload work.

Here's my app.js file

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/tasks', function(req, res) {
  res.render('form');
});
app.post('/tasks', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files);
  res.send('ok');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

exports = module.exports = app;
```

And here's my form.jade view file:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Task Upload
  body
    form(action='/tasks', method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data')
      input(name='task', type='file')
      input(type='submit')
```

Everytime I try to upload a file, `req.files` logs out `undefined`. Can anyone save me out from this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following in your app.js

```
app.configure(function(){
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.bodyParser({keepExtensions:true,uploadDir:path.join(__dirname,'/files'}));

});
```

And then try to access as follows;

```
req.files.task
```

It is recommended not to use bodyParser, but to simply define the type of handling you want. In your case since its file uploading, you can enable it as follows

```
   app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.multipart());
   });
```

You can read about why using bodyParser() is not a good idea in the following link.

http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html

Comment: Thank you! I just ignore the bodyParser, really stupid. And the link is also helpful.

Answer (score 5):

In **Express 4**, ***req.files*** is no longer available on the ***req*** object by default. 
To access uploaded files on the ***req.files*** object, use multipart-handling middleware like **busboy, multer, formidable, multiparty, connect-multiparty,**.