# Upload files with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this code in order to upload files with node.js:

```
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    // or, as `req.files` is only provided by the multipart middleware, you could 
    // add just that if you're not concerned with parsing non-multipart uploads, 
    // like:
    app.use(express.multipart());

    app.get('/',function(req,res){
    fs.readFile('uploadHTML.html',function (err, data){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Content-Length':data.length});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });

    });
    app.post('/upload',function(req,res)
    {
    console.log(req.files);
    fs.readFile(req.files.displayImage.path, function (err, data) {
      // ...
      var newPath = __dirname;
      fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
        res.redirect("back");
      });
    });
 });
```

Here is the HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="uploadForm"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="/upload"
      method="post">
  <input type="file" id="userPhotoInput" name="displayImage" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<span id="status" />
<img id="uploadedImage" />


</body>
</html>
```

When I upload the file, it gives me the next error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayImage' of undefined at c:\NodeInstall\nodejs\express.js:42:22 at callbacks (c:\NodeInstall\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37) at param (c:\NodeInstall\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11) at pass (c:\NodeInstall\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5) at Router._dispatch (c:\NodeInstall\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5) at Object.router (c:\NodeInstall\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10) at next (c:\NodeInstall\nodejs\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15) at Object.expressInit [as handle] (c:\NodeInstall\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\middleware.js:30:5) at next (c:\NodeInstall\nodejs\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15) at Object.query [as handle] (c:\NodeInstall\nodejs\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\query.js:45:5)
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128451/express-cant-upload-file-req-files-is-undefined

Comment: What version of Express are you using?

Answer (score 5):

I do recommend you to use awesome module https://github.com/domharrington/fileupload for handling file uploads in node/express.

```
var fileupload = require('fileupload').createFileUpload('/uploadDir').middleware

app.post('/upload', fileupload, function(req, res) {
  // files are now in the req.body object along with other form fields
  // files also get moved to the uploadDir specified
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to upload files could be using something like this

Jade template

```
form.data(action='/user/register', method='post', class="long-fields", enctype='multipart/form-data')
  input(type="text" name="name")
  input(name='fileLogo', type='file')
  input(type="submit" value="Register")
```

Controller

```
formidable = require('formidable'); //file upload handling via form
uuid = require('node-uuid'); //Unique ID
path = require('path'); //Path compiler
fs = require('fs'); //FileSystem

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.keepExtensions = false;
form.maxFieldsSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; //2mb

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

    console.log(fields);
    console.log(files);

    fs.readFile(files.fileLogo.path, function (err, data) {
        var pathNew = __dirname + '/../../uploads/' + uuid.v1() + path.extname(files.fileLogo.name)

        fs.writeFile(pathNew, data, function (err) {
            console.log('uploaded', pathNew);
        });
    });

    res.send(jade.renderFile( settings.pathLess + prefix + '/register.jade', {
        req : req
    }));
});
```