# File not uploading properly

Tags: html, json, node.js

EDIT: Edited it using Mikhail's suggestion. Got closer to the solution

Hi I am trying to upload a JSON file using nodejs but for some reason it says my file is undefined. A file appears in my Public folder that contains the contents of the uploaded file however. I was wondering if someone would be able to help me out. Thanks

Here is the HTML

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/file-upload">
  <input type="file" name="theFile" >
    <input type="submit" class = "submit">
</form>
```

EDIT: Here is the server.js

```
 app.post('/testtwilio',upload.single('theFile'),function(req, res, next) {
 console.log('FIRST TEST: ' + req.file);

});
```

Here is the JSON file

```
[{"name":"FIRST LAST","date":"12/22/2016","number":"7523924324"}]
```

Here is what is being logged

```
FIRST TEST: [object Object]
```

Comment: Try with `console.log( req);`  or `console.log(req.files);` for debugging purpose.

Comment: Have you set up [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)?

Comment: EDIT: with req it says [object Object] and with req.files it says undefined

Comment: and I haven't set multer up, is that required?

Comment: i tried it with multer but getting the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload files with node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263307/upload-files-with-node-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `JSON.stringify(req.files)` to `JSON.stringify(req.file)`

Full code

HTML

```
<form id = "uploadForm" enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "/api/file" method = "post">
    <input type="file" name="userFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

JS

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
var app = express()

app.get('/',function(req,res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/api/file', upload.single('userFile'), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.file))
})

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

Note:

File name which you use in `multer.single()` method should match name in input `<input type="file" name="userFile" />`

Comment: I did that and it returned [object Object].

Comment: @Nik it's strange, because I have experienced the code before answer to your question, and with your JSON file `[{"name":"FIRST LAST","date":"12/22/2016","number":"7523924324"}]` all should work

Comment: @Nik You need to get contents of the file after upload ?

Comment: I got it to work finally! Thanks so much for taking the time to record a video, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `.single(...)` method the file will be in `req.file`.