# FTP progress info with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ftp

I want to develop a system that allow user to upload files from browser to server then the uploaded files will be transferred to a FTP server. I did it by using ftp-client module already. Now, i want to check the progress info to see how many percents each file is being transferred to FTP server. Could you let me know how to do it ? Which FTP modules could help me this ? Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload files with node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263307/upload-files-with-node-js)

Comment: @karan: No, my issue is progress info of files uploaded to FTP server from a node server

Comment: Solved. There is a 'data' event of readable stream which provides transferred data.