# Uploading file from angular to node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ionic3, ionic-native

I am new to this thing, can anyone explain me that, if i am hitting an API endpoint from angular to send a image/video. How should i write my `route.post` route in express.js to get the incoming image/video.

I am using the FileTransfer Ionic native plugin to send the captured image/video to my server.

```
this.mediaCapture.captureImage()
    .then((data: MediaFile[]) => {
            let option = {
            enableHighAccuracy : true 
          }

          this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(option)
          .then((resp) => {
            let ionic: LatLng = new LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
            const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
            let options: FileUploadOptions = {
              fileKey: 'File',
              fileName: data['0'].name,
              params: {
                postTitle: 'hey there',
                postDesc: 'jshfdjnsbdkjcfweigfc,ndsbfckjg',
                postLat : ionic.lat,
                postLng : ionic.lng,
                userId  : this.loggedInUserId  
              }
            }

            fileTransfer.upload(data['0'].fullPath, 'https://***************.com/images/postImages', options)
             .then((data) => {
               console.log('image has been uploaded');
             }, (err) => {
               // error
             })

          })
        })
```

first i am capturing the image then the location coordinates and then i am sending the file and data to the API enpoint.

```
router.post('/postImages', function(req, res) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        console.log(req.body);
        var sql = "INSERT INTO posts (post_title, post_desc, post_lat, post_lng, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        var inserts = [req.body.postTitle, req.body.postDesc, req.body.postLat, req.body.postLng, req.body.userId];
        sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
        console.log(sql);
        connection.query(sql, function(error, results) {
            res.json(results);
            connection.release();
            if(error) throw error;
        });
    });
});
```

the API hit is properly done but i am not reciving any thing in the req body, also there is no file in the directory. Please help me i am at the brink of my Final Year Project submission.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263307/upload-files-with-node-js

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload