# file Upload node js

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.post('/upload/notes',function(req,res){
     if(req.files){
         console.log("files");
        // filename is the id of the html input field
         var file = req.files.filename;
             }
}
```

---

now I am trying to upload a file using android device using retrofit .
What is the id equivalent in retrofit .
If not this , Please suggest a way where I can upload an image or file using postman which i will handle with a route as given above . 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqDA2.png)

as in the image , there is a route for "upload/notes " but it wont load for some reason . I am new to node and I cant understand the problem .

Comment: I wasn't able to . as the "if" condition was being ignored because the condition inside the braces weren't legal . now I am planning to look into req.body and see where it goes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express can't upload file, req.files is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128451/express-cant-upload-file-req-files-is-undefined)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43041225/6640982

In Express 4, req.files is no longer available on the req object by default. To access uploaded files on the req.files object, use multipart-handling middleware like busboy, multer, formidable, multiparty, connect-multiparty,.

Answer (score -2):

```
    //**create a page name as fileUplaodTesting.js which consist of html form too**
   var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var formidable = require('formidable');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    if (req.url == '/fileupload') {

        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
      var newpath = './public/' + files.filetoupload.name;
      fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File moved Succesfully');
         res.end();
      });
 });

  }else
  {
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
      res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
      res.write('<input type="submit">');
      res.write('</form>');
      return res.end();
  }

}).listen(8080);
```